# Count "null" to strand for integer

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning bytes:

```
In [3]: bytes("a", "utf-8")
Out[3]: b'a'

In [4]: bytes("a", "utf-8")[0]
Out[4]: 97

In [5]: chr(97)
Out[5]: 'a'
```

As for the character, it's easy to understand, but for the integer:

```
In [7]: bytes(2)
Out[7]: b'\x00\x00'

In [8]: bytes(3)
Out[8]: b'\x00\x00\x00'

In [9]: bytes(3).decode()
Out[9]: '\x00\x00\x00'
```

Does it count the number of "null" to stand for the integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray):

> bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes